# JQuery applying hover effect to the whole class

Tags: jquery, class, hover, effect

I have a problem and I couldn't find a specific answer anywhere.

I have downloaded a JQuery plugin as this is my first java script attempt and I am trying to apply this zoom hover effect to each image. Insted it applies the effect the whole class and applies a single effect to all of the thumbnails.

HTML

```
<div class="gallery">
   <a href="" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/1.png" alt="" /></span></a>
   <a href="" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/2.png" alt="" /></span></a>
   <a href="" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/3.png" alt="" /></span></a>
   <a href="" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/4.png" alt="" /></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery {
   height: auto;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   margin-top: 200px;
}

.gallery li {
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   display:inline-block;
}

.gallery li a.thumb {
   width: 314px; 
   height: 177px;
   padding: 0px;
   cursor: auto;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.gallery').hoverpulse().each(function() {
      var $img = $(this);
      var link = $img.attr('data-link');
      $img.attr('title','Goto: ' + link);
      $img.click(function() {
         window.open(link);
         return false;
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: What JQuery plugin are you using? Try to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Try changing your selector to `$(.gallery img' ).hoverpulse()`

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.gallery img').hoverpulse().each(function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        var link = $img.attr('data-link');
        $img.attr('title','Goto: ' + link);
        $img.click(function() {
            window.open(link);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```